# EF Core and Automapper Not Playing Well with Nested Child Relationships

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, mediatr, ef-core-5.0

Either I am not searching for the proper terms, or this topic has not been properly covered.  I am creating a dynamic navigational system for an app and using the Clean Architecture pattern so graciously documented by Jason Taylor and am using Automapper.

None of the examples I have found use a reciprocal relationship.  Most define the relationship as ParentEntity and ChildEntity.  In my case, it's a single Entity, MenuItem.  My entity is defined below:

```cs
public class MenuItem : AuditableEntity // this inheritance includes properties such as created by and date
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Args { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Authorized { get; set; } // list of roles

    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public Guid MenuId { get; set; }
    public MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    public IList<MenuItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<MenuItem>();
}
```

Entity type configuration:

```cs
public class MenuItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MenuItem>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MenuItem> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(mi => mi.Action).HasMaxLength(128);
            builder.Property(mi => mi.Area).HasMaxLength(128);
            builder.Property(mi => mi.Authorized).HasMaxLength(1024);
            builder.Property(mi => mi.Controller).HasMaxLength(256);
            builder.Property(mi => mi.Icon).HasMaxLength(64);
            builder.Property(mi => mi.Title).HasMaxLength(128);
            builder.HasOne(mi => mi.Menu).WithMany(m => m.Items).HasForeignKey(mi => mi.MenuId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            builder.HasOne(mi => mi.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Items).HasForeignKey(mi => mi.ParentId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Property(e => e.CreatedById).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(e => e.UpdatedById).HasMaxLength(64);
            builder.Ignore(e => e.HardDelete);

            builder.ToTable("MenuItem");
        }
    }
```

My view model is almost identical:

```cs
public class MenuItemVm
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Args { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Authorized { get; set; } // list of roles

    public MenuVm Menu { get; set; }
    public Guid MenuId { get; set; }
    public MenuItemVm Parent { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    public IList<MenuItemVm> Items { get; set; } = new List<MenuItemVm>();
}
```

I have a profile configured as the following:

```cs
public class MenuItemMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MenuItemMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<MenuItem, MenuItemVm>();
            CreateMap<MenuItemVm, MenuItem>();

            // could have just used this I believe to replace the above 2 lines:
            // CreateMap<MenuItem, MenuItemVm>().ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<CreateMenuItemCommand, MenuItem>();
            CreateMap<UpdateMenuItemCommand, MenuItem>();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, by the definition of the entity, I am able to create *(in theory, but not practical)* endless levels of menu >> menu item >> sub menu item >> sub menu item such as the following:

```
LeftNavigationMenu (Menu)
    + Vendors (MenuItemVm)
        - Dashboard (MenuItemVm)
        - Search (MenuItemVm)
        + Reports (MenuItemVm)
            - Outstanding Unpaid Purchase Orders (MenuItemVm)
            - New Vendors (MenuItemVm)
    + Customers (MenuItemVm)
        - Dashboard (MenuItemVm)
        - Search (MenuItemVm)
        + Reports (MenuItemVm)
            - Outstanding Unpaid Invoices (MenuItemVm)
            - New Customers (MenuItemVm)
    + Sales (MenuItemVm)
        - Dashboard (MenuItemVm)
        - Create Invoice (MenuItemVm)
    - Financial Reports (MenuItemVm)
```

In my Mediatr query class, I am using the EF `Include` method and the Automapper `ProjectTo` method and I assume I am missing something as the result does not load the Parent nor the Items:

```cs
// (abbreviated snippet)
public async Task<IList<MenuItemVm>> Handle(GetMenuItemsForMenuQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // the following properly returns the menu items with the Parent property populated as well as the
    // Items collection, that is what led me to believe I have something wrong in my mapping profile:
    var test = await _context.MenuItems.Include(ay => ay.Menu).Include(ay => ay.Parent).Where(rp => rp.MenuId == request.MenuId).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    return await _context.MenuItems.Include(ay => ay.Menu).Include(ay => ay.Parent).Where(rp => rp.MenuId == request.MenuId).ProjectTo<MenuItemVm>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

What do I have wrong?  Is it my Mapping Profile or is it my linq query or both?

Comment: You don't need `Include`, but you must set `RecursiveQueriesMaxDepth`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Lucian, but I am unable to find RecursiveQueriesMaxDepth documented anywhere.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant :) Anyway, recursive queries are a bad idea, it's best to avoid them. There are many similar questions.